# From which folder can I get the Zim Desktop Wiki document files?

Tags: data-recovery, notes

My Linux has recently crashed (my own fault) and I had some important info in my Zim desktop wiki. Even though I can access all files within the drive of crashed OS from live USB, I don't know where the Zim documents I need actually are. Copy pasting which files will let me view my documents in a Linux operating system with Zim installed and which folder are they in?

Comment: they might be in /home/usr/Notebooks/

Answer (score 0):

If you have not customized Zim document path,
then you can find its folder in `~/Notebooks/Notes` as first launch wizard shows:

[image: first launch of Zim]

Other possibility is to find `.zim` folders and `*.zim` files in your file-system.